# Marking points of intersection between two curves

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm trying to illustrate the solutions numerically and graphically for an equation such as `Tan[x] == x`. I think I did everything ok except I wanted to mark each intersection between `Tan[x]` and `x`.

Does anyone know how such a thing can be done?

Comment: `Comment by the OP (migrated from the question) ->` ** I'm sorry if I'm not 'commenting' properly. I'll figure it out when I get more time here. I wanted to say THANKS to EVERYONE that posted. This is exactly what I was looking for. I will use all the input and make sure I learn from what was given. What a goldmine this site is for learning something like this. Thanks again, it's greatly appreciated!!

Comment: See also the solution using [RootsInRange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42304/finding-the-intersection-of-a-curve-with-an-interpolation-function/42538#42538). This solution is more general as it will work when either the exact intersections are not known, or NSolve fails.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Edited to make it a function.
For the strange `Exclusions` specification I use below, see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10502/193). Thanks to @Oleksandr and @JM for their great comments.

```
plInters[{f1_, f2_}, {min_, max_}] :=
 Module[{sol, x},
         sol = x /. NSolve[f1[x] == f2[x] && min < x < max, x];
         Framed@Show[
                  ListPlot[{#, f1[#]} & /@ sol, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]],
                  Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, min, max}, Exclusions -> {True, f2[x] == 10, f1[x] == 10}]
    ]
  ]


GraphicsRow[plInters[#, {-10, 10}] & /@ {{# &, Tan}, {Tan, Coth}, {Sin, 1/# &}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Damn, yours is better.

Comment: @kale That is one of the good things in this site. You can always find other ways.

Comment: Anyway definite +1 from me.

Comment: I don't really know why `Plot` can sometimes determine exclusions properly and sometimes not. Still, this'll look a bit better if you set `Exclusions -> Pi/2 Range[-5, 5, 2]` for `Plot` (otherwise, it may be harder for students to see that these aren't really solutions).

Comment: @Oleksandr, for exclusions for the tangent function, it's slightly neater to use `Exclusions -> {Cos[x] == 0}`...

Comment: @J.M. I forgot that `Exclusions` can accept equations. Mathematically, that's a lot neater! However, it seems to have a strange effect on the curve for `g[x]`, whereas giving specific values doesn't. Another `Exclusions` oddity...

Comment: @J.M. Edited with exclusions driven by `Cos@x==0`.Note that `Sin@x == 1` doesn't work.

Comment: @belisarius `Sin[x + Pi/2] == 0` works. It seems that `Exclusions` cannot determine the extreme positions.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov see update

Comment: @belisarius Why `Exclusions -> {True, f[x] == 1}` works? BTW, `Exclusions -> {True, f[x] == 70}` works much better: there are no breaks in the plot of `g` at all.

Comment: @Alexey I tried to explain why here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10502/193. It gets the plot refinement routine to work to your advantage.

Comment: @belisarius You mean that `Exclusions` is deeply integrated into the plot refinement routine, interesting!

Comment: Could someone please explain what does `Exclusions -> {True, ...}` do?

Answer (score 53):

**Update 3:** Using `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` to get the intersection points ([see also](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156975/125)):

```
showIntersections = Show[#, Graphics @{Red, PointSize[Large], 
      Point @ Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections @ #}] &;
```

Using the two examples in the original answer:

```
Row[showIntersections /@ {Plot[{Cos[x], x Sin[x]}, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, 
    ImageSize -> 400],
   Plot[{Tan[x], x Sin[x]}, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, ImageSize -> 400, 
    Exclusions -> Range[-5 Pi/2, 5 Pi/2, Pi]]}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can also use `MeshFunctions`:

```
  Plot[{Cos[x], x Sin[x]}, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {(Cos[#] - # Sin[#]) &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
     MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image: plot of Cos[x] and x Sin[x]]

**Update:** Dealing with `Tan[x]` using `Exclusions`

```
Plot[{Tan[x], x Sin[x]}, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {(Tan[#] - # Sin[#]) &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
   Exclusions -> Range[-5 Pi/2, 5 Pi/2, Pi]]
   (* or Exclusions -> (Cos[x] == 0) *)
```

[image: plot of Tan[x] and x Sin[x]]

**Update 2:** Using just `Mesh` and `MeshStyle`:

```
points = NSolve[Tan[x] == x Sin[x] && -3 Pi < x < 3 Pi, x][[All, 1, 2]];
Plot[{Tan[x], x Sin[x]}, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi},
  Mesh -> {points},
  MeshStyle -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]},
  Exclusions -> Range[-5 Pi/2, 5 Pi/2, Pi]]
(* same picture as above *)
```

Comment: very nice! :) $ $

Comment: This has [some problems](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3ywBf.png) with the exclusions :(

Comment: @R.M thank you. Belisarius, right... without `excluding` the vertical segments of the `Tan` function (using `Exclusions` or `RegionFunction`) `MeshFunctions` do not work.

Comment: But that is not always easy > http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10501/193