# Plotting discontinuous functions without spurious vertical segments

Tags: plotting

Consider the plot of this discontinuous function:

```
f[x_] := If[2 < x < 3, 0, x]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image: plot of a discontinuous function]

I'd like to plot that without the vertical segments.
Modifying the function `f` is not allowed.

ADDED: I should've said more about the restriction on modifying `f`.
In the real application where this came up, `f` is a messy thing that should be treated as a black box.  So we can't pick out the discontinuity, and probably can't invert the function either.

Comment: These are amazing answers; thanks so much everyone!

Comment: see [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/03/14/mathematica-qa-excluding-points-from-plots/) for Mathematica Q&A: Excluding Points from Plots (from Wolfram)

Comment: Is this the community's first question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I looked for a way without redefining the function and not using explicit knowledge about it (so it can be generalized)

```
pl[f_, lims_] := Module[{eps = 0.05},
   Off[InverseFunction::"ifun"];
   Print@Plot[f[u], {u, lims[[1]], lims[[2]]},
      Exclusions ->
       {{f[u] == f[InverseFunction[f][u]], Abs[(f[u] - f[u + eps])] > 10 eps},
        {f[u] == f[InverseFunction[f][u]], Abs[(f[u] - f[u - eps])] > 10 eps}}]
    On[InverseFunction::"ifun"];
   ];

(* Testing *)

f[x_] := If[2 < x < 3, 0, x];
pl[f, {0, 5}];
pl[Tan, {0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Ok, this one does not use InverseFunction, and identifies discontinuities, as far as I tested it:

```
(*Function Definition*)
pl[f_, lims_]:= Plot[f[u],{u, lims[[1]], lims[[2]]},Exclusions->{True, f[u] == 1}];

(*--------Test--------*)
flist = {
   If[Abs@Sin@# > .5, 1, 0] &,
   If[2 < # < 3, 0, #] &,
   1/Sin@# + 1 &,
   Tan};
pk = Table[{Plot[fun[x], {x, 0, 10}], pl[fun, {0, 10}]}, {fun, flist}];
GraphicsGrid[pk]
```

Here are side by side the results from Plot (without Options) and from this function:

[image]

**Edit 2**

Found a counterexample, and perhaps some comprehension about what is going on there.

```
   f = If[Abs@Sin@# > .5, 2, 5] &
```

Does not work.  Why? It's easy ... the discontinuity does not cross f[u]==1 ...

Doing a Reap-Sow on the Plot (as in @rcollyer's answer) I saw that adding the Exclusions with f[u]==1 adds a few points to the trace just around f[u]==1 and seems that that is the trigger for excluding the discontinuities from the domain.

Now trying to find a way to change the f[u]==1 for something that works better ...

**Edit 3**

Found a way with a discrete derivative, a tricky thing.

Like this:

```
(*Function Definition*)
pl[f_, lims_]  :=  Plot[f[u], {u, lims[[1]], lims[[2]]},
                              Exclusions -> {(f[u] - f[u + .1])/.1 == 10, 
                                             (f[u] - f[u + .1])/.1 == -10}];
```

Note two issues:

1. I had to remove the "True" or "Automatic" option from the Exlusions
2. Taking Abs[] for joining the two Exclusion equalities does not work since it's monitoring the evolution of the lhs ...

Comment: Okay, simple question: why does the addition of f[u]==1 help?  `Exclusions -> True`, alone, does not work, so why does the addition of the function work?  I'm honestly confused.  BTW: +1, simple and clever.

Comment: Wow, this seems like a definitive improvement to Plot itself.  My only reservation about it is what happens when the function is not invertible...

Comment: @dreeves I am not using InverseFunction anymore. And trig functions are not invertible ... I am still trying to find a counterexample where this doesn't work, since I am not blind-confident about the method.

Comment: @rcollyer I was experimenting a lot. I really do not understand why this work, but I am still not able to find a counter-example.

Comment: @belisarius, per edit 2, changed the exclusion to `f[u]==u` and it only excluded the second and third discontinuity.  So, you're definitely on to something.  My thinking is that you'll need to know a little about the domain/range of your function in order to properly set up the exclusions, i.e. plot it without the exclusions first.

Comment: @rcollyer Perhaps pre-processing the plot on a Table first. I'm working on that. Also trying to get something from a finite approx to the derivative, but this one seems tricky (but more elegant).

Comment: @rcollyer See edit. Tricky indeed.

Comment: @belisarius, interesting.  But, it fails for me with `If[Abs@Sin@# > .5,1,0]&`, however reducing `h` to 0.01 works.  Of course what happens if the slope of 10 is a valid part of the equation?  Consider: `Sin[1/#^2] &`, at least some of it is excluded.  (Yes, it is a pathological example, but math wouldn't be fun without it.)

Comment: @rcollyer For functions with rapid oscillations, adding MaxRecursions -> 15 probably helps, although if you have derivatives going from +Inf to -Inf the curve will show holes _somewhere_. Also, please be aware that finding a full amendment for the Exclusions bug (I think it IS a bug) is out of the scope :). A fix for plotting piecewise-like functions with shapes like the one on the question and a few more non seriously pathological cases is more on the mark here. Regarding the epsilon and h values, I'm sure some tuning is needed ... (or just leaving them as parameters)

Comment: @belisarius, definitely a bug, as the documentation specifies that `Exclusions->True` is supposed to work automatically. Maybe it has trouble with the `If` instead of `UnitStep`, but either should work.  As a former software tester, I have a pathological need to break software, so I just had to see where your solution would break.

Comment: Is this the community's first answer?

Answer (score 16):

The answer is [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exclusions.html?q=Exclusions&lang=en) as follows:

[image]

In this case, your excluding the points where there are discontinuities.  It will also accept functional definitions.

**Edit**:
Since you state you can't pick out the exclusions, I assume you mean that unlike the example you gave the exclusions are not known *a priori*.  And, assuming that `InverseFunction` does not work for you, as per [belisarius's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382610/plotting-discontinuous-functions-without-spurious-vertical-segments/4382799#4382799), then you will have to generate them "by hand".  The best bet would be to use [`EvaluationMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html?q=EvaluationMonitor&lang=en) to acquire the points `Plot` uses, like in the example

```
data = Reap[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, Sin[x]}]] ][[-1, 1]]
```

and compare the numerical derivatives on both sides of each point

```
der = (Subtract@@#[[All,2]])/(Subtract@@#[[All,1]])
Select[Partition[data, 3, 1], Abs[ der@#[[{1,2}]] - der@#[[{2,3}]] ] > tol& ]
```

where the difference exceeds some tolerance.  You'll need to then pull out the offending point, but it should be the only one that exists in 3 consecutive sublists.  This then gives you your exclusions.

**Edit, part 2**: In the continuing jockeying for the "correct" solution to this, I found in the Applications section of the [`Plot` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot&lang=en) a method that is effective for all of the inital tests used by @belisarius:  `Exclusions -> {1/f[x] == 0}`, and `Exclusions -> {1/D[f,x] == 0}` works for my pathological example of `Sin[1/x^2]`.  Unfortunately, both still fail for `If[Abs@Sin@# > .5, 2, 5]&`. Additionally, the use of the derivative fails for all of the initial tests and spuriously removes pieces when combined with `1/f[x]==0`.

Comment: Here is another nice way to find the discontinuities http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Aug/msg00387.html. The first function def lacks the "==" sign before the "z"

Comment: It should be noted that `Select` is calculating something close to the second derivative (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences), and it may be simpler to think of it in those terms.

Comment: Can something like this be adapted for a `ListPlot`, where you have discrete samples of the function? I want to exclude points that are near a discontinuity (because the samples here are very unreliable)

Comment: @becko you'll have to mask them yourself. Although, I'd exchange the problematic points for `Missing[]` as `ListPlot` will produce something similar to `Exclusions` in that case.

Answer (score 10):

This works:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x < 2}, {0, x < 3}, {x, x > 3}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

and you also have the advantage that `Piecewise` is derivable (see docs).

EDIT: But if you can not change `f`, then you can do this:

```
Plot[ f[x], {x, 0, 5}, Exclusions -> {2, 3} ]
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer, though note the restriction that I don't want to modify the function f.

Comment: Oops. rcollyer posted his answer while I added Exclusions to mine. :-)

Comment: @gdelfino: it took me a few moments to find it and generate the graphs.

Comment: @gdelfino, I was trying to imply that if it hadn't taken me that long, I would have posted it much sooner.  But, it seems that I completely missed that point in my comment.

Comment: @rcollyer Thank's fine. It is incredible how fast people answer good questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: @gdelfino, sometimes it seems like it is a race trying to answer a question well and thoroughly before someone else does. Reminds me of some areas of science, in general.

Comment: Really, sometimes simpler is better. Despite @dreeves stipulation that the function `f` not be modified, it's just as easy, if not easier, to regard such a function defined in pieces as a `Piecewise` rather than as given by a conditional `If` expression.

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out by Wolfram, the following will also work.  Not as powerful as Exclusions or
Piecewise, of course:

```
f[x_] := If[2 < x < 3, 0, x]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2, 3, 5}]
```

**Update:** This code might have worked in earlier versions of Mathematica. As of version 11, it does not work anymore.

Comment: +1 One of those features I usually forget about ...

Comment: +1 I cannot recall seeing this before.

Comment: Checking back,I found out about this in the following Mathmergency [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oastu77JRVo).  Not, as I thought, a Wolfram presentation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Does this still work? On v11 I get a weird output: ```System`ProtoPlotDump`iPlot[Plot, System`ProtoPlotDump`obj$1974, 
 f[x], {x, 0, 2, 3, 5}]```

Comment: @becko It fails in version 10.1 as well.  Likely it was experimental syntax that was rejected.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your original question, (I assume you have your reasons for not using the `Piecewise` solution given by gdelfino)

```
f[x_]:=If[2<x<3,0,x]
Plot[f[x],{x,0,5},Exclusions->{2,3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am getting late here, but in Mathematica 11 (and perhaps earlier versions) the ExclusionsStyle option would do the job, also for arbitrary functions...

```
f[x_] := If[2 < x < 3, 0, x]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, ExclusionsStyle -> None]
```

Another example that also works

```
f[x_] := Tan[x]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, ExclusionsStyle -> None, PlotRange -> {-20, 20}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This definitely comes late, but I think another elegant solution is to use in place of `Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]` the instruction

```
DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, 0, 5, 0.1}, PlotStyle -> "LineColor" -> None]
```

[image: The result of DiscretePlot]

I know it doesn't exactly answer the question, but for illustrative purposes it may be more than enough.
For functions defined via `NIntegrate[]` and not known in closed form, moreover, all the above solutions fail because conditions like `Exclusions -> {1/f[x] == 0}` do not work.