# Exclusion disappears but style doesn't work

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

Consider this code:

```
f[x_]:=(6 + 4 x + x^2 - x^3)/(x-2)
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10},
Exclusions -> {2},
ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

It produces this image.

[image]

Note that the vertical exclusion is removed, but it is not styled with a red, dashed line. On the other hand, this works.

```
f[x_]:=(6 + 4 x + x^2 - x^3)/(x-2)
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10},
Exclusions -> {-2 + x == 0},
ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

[image]

How come?

Comment: Exclusions inner workings aren't trivial. See for example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10502/193

Comment: I believe the quick answer is that `Exclusions` needs to return a `Boolean`.

Comment: According to the documentation, `Exclusions -> 2` is not correct syntax.  However, `Exclusions -> {2}` is.  Both cause the exclusion to appear but none will work with styling.  `Exclusions -> {x==2}` works with styling.  This looks like a bug to me and I'm tagging it as such.  Can you please report to Wolfram and let us know what they said?  In the bug report I would reference the `Exclusions -> {2}` syntax as this is clearly documented.

Comment: I am guessing that the function is `f[x_] = (x + 1)^2 (x - 3)/(2 - x);`; however, you should includes its definition in your question.

Comment: I did report this to Wolfram.

Comment: And I got this response from Wolfram feedback: Hi David,

Thanks for your message and for taking the time to send in the invaluable feedback. Indeed this is a wrong behaviour of Exclusions. Our developers are aware of the issue and are working to resolve it. I will keep you informed if any updates on this topic.

Thanks again for bringing the issue to our attention, most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this is what it looks like on 11.0.1.

[image]