# Plotting issues with n-root function

Tags: education

I've been getting issues with plotting a function I've written to calculate the maximum height a floating body can float in a polytrope atmosphere dependant on a weight, here is the function;

```
X[ml_] := Power[(v Subscript[\[Rho], h] + 6000 kg + ml)/(
v Subscript[\[Rho], 0]), ((n - 1))^-1]

z[ml_] := -(X[ml] - 1) (n Subscript[h, 0])/(n - 1)
```

I would like to plot it, but I get an error that regardless of googling I can't seem to find an answer.
The error message being:

```
In[207]:= Plot[z[ml], ml]

Out[207]= System`ProtoPlotDump`iPlot[Plot, \System`ProtoPlotDump`obj$53256, z[ml], ml]
```

I found, while googling, this link ([Plotting discontinuous functions without spurious vertical segments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10501/plotting-discontinuous-functions-without-spurious-vertical-segments)) with close to the same error message. However, my function shouldn't be discontinuous in its entire range and I don't understand enough of mathematica to apply this example to mine.

I tried plotting the function again within a specific range (1m to 3000m)
and this time the graph appears but not actual plot. (see image)

What is the error in my code? Or more accurately, how can I plot this function?

To clarify, my function requires values to be given in kg and returns values in m (metres). Like so

```
In[217]:= z[300 kg]

Out[217]= 28384.6 m
```

(albeit the returned value seems a little high...but that is a different issue)

When trying set that range, mathematica just returns the function again.

```
In[216]:= Plot[z[ml], {ml, 1 kg, 3000 kg}]

Out[216]= Plot[z[ml], {ml, 1 kg, 3000 kg}]
```

Thank you for the help!
Here is a screen shot of mathematica, I'm running version 11.[image]

Comment: You're missing a couple of definitions?

Comment: Since you are using quantities, look at the documentation for [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html)

Comment: @Feyre Ahh, Sorry I didn't consider posting the entire code.
v = 8434 m^3
Roh_h = 0.1785kg/m^3
Roh_0 = 1.225 kg/m^3
h_0 = 8434
n = 1.25

their actual values I suppose for the question arn't important, but they are defined. Sorry if it's unclear to anyone

Comment: @BobHanlon I will have a read. and return if I don't manage to solve. thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const = {v -> Quantity[8434, "Meters"^3],
   Subscript[ρ, h] -> Quantity[0.1785, "Kilograms"/"Meters"^3],
   Subscript[ρ, 0] -> Quantity[1.225 , "Kilograms"/"Meters"^3],
   Subscript[h, 0] -> Quantity[8434, "Meters"],
   n -> 1.25};
```

**Note** that I made `Subscript[h, 0]` a quantity (`"Meters"`) rather than the dimensionless constant provided.

```
X[ml_] := Power[(v Subscript[ρ, h] + Quantity[6000, "Kilograms"] + 
     ml)/(v Subscript[ρ, 0]), ((n - 1))^-1]

z[ml_] := -(X[ml] - 1) (n Subscript[h, 0])/(n - 1)

z[Quantity[300, "Kilograms"]] /. const

(*  Quantity[28432.1, "Meters"]  *)

Plot[z[Quantity[ml, "Kilograms"]] /. const, {ml, 1, 3000},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 FrameLabel -> {"ml in kilograms", "z in meters"}]
```

[image]

Or to convert to kilometers

```
Plot[UnitConvert[z[Quantity[ml, "Kilograms"]] /. const, "Kilometers"], {ml, 1,
   3000},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 FrameLabel -> {"ml in kilograms", "z in kilometers"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! after reading about quantities I immediately tried to plot without my constants...which worked of course. Just after you posted this, I was in the process of trying to plot with quantities...which didn't work :D, Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
v = 8434 ;
Subscript[\[Rho], h] = 0.1785  ;
Subscript[\[Rho], 0] = 1.225  ;
Subscript[h, 0] = 8434 ;
n = 1.25;
X[ml_] := 
 Power[(v Subscript[\[Rho], h] + 6000 + 
     ml)/(v Subscript[\[Rho], 0]), ((n - 1))^-1]
z[ml_] := -(X[ml] - 1) (n Subscript[h, 0])/(n - 1)

Plot[z[ml], {ml, 1 , 3000}]
```

Out:
[image]