# How can I set characteristic variables for NondimensionalizationTransform?

Tags: dimension-reduction

Apparantly the [NondimensionalizationTransform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NondimensionalizationTransform.html) is not throughly documented. There is an [SO answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219555/61273) explaining how to use it, but I am having trouble applying it to my problem.

I am trying to handle a simple steady-state energy conservation equation in fluid flow:

```
dimX = QuantityVariable[Superscript[x, "*"], "Length"];
dimY = QuantityVariable[Superscript[y, "*"], "Length"];
dimSF = QuantityVariable[Superscript[\[Psi], "*"], "Velocity" "Length"];
dimU = D[dimSF[dimX, dimY], dimY];
dimV = -D[dimSF[dimX, dimY], dimX];
dimT = QuantityVariable[Superscript[T, "*"], "Temperature"];
\[Kappa] = QuantityVariable["\[Kappa]", "ThermalDiffusivity"];
dimHeatEq = {dimU, dimV} . Transpose[Grad[dimT[dimX, dimY], {dimX, dimY}]] == \[Kappa] Laplacian[dimT[dimX, dimY], {dimX, dimY}]
```

The resulting `dimHeatEq` is:

$${\psi^*}^{(0,1)}\left(x^*,y^*\right) {T^*}^{(1,0)}\left(x^*,y^*\right)-{\psi^*}^{(1,0)}\left(x^*,y^*\right)
   {T^*}^{(0,1)}\left(x^*,y^*\right)=\kappa 
   \left({T^*}^{(0,2)}\left(x^*,y^*\right)+{T^*}^{(2,0)}\left(x^*,y^*\right)\right)$$

Here, $\psi$ is the streamfunction.

Then I tried to nondimensionalize the equation:

```
NondimensionalizationTransform[dimHeatEq, {dimX, dimY, dimSF, dimT}, {x, y, \[Psi], T}]
```

This gave me a equation with bunch of `K[1]`s and `K[2]`s.

The multipliers are:

```
NondimensionalizationTransform[dimHeatEq, {dimX, dimY, dimSF, dimT}, {x, y, \[Psi], T}, "NondimensionalizationMultipliers"]
(* <|x^*->K[1]m,y^*->K[2]m,\[Psi]^*->\[Kappa],T^*->K[3]K|> *)
```

So it seems that `x^*` is scaled with `K[1]` and `y^*` is with `K[2]`.

Instead of these random variables, I want to scale `x^*` with `L` and `y^*` with `A L`. (`A` is the aspect ratio. See [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/thermocapillary-flows-on-heated-substrates-with-sinusoidal-topography/3B13651D652223ACC4038BB79A1932EA) for reference.) Can I pass these values to `NondimensionalizationTransform`?