# Solution Transcedental Equation with(Graphical method)

Tags: equation-solving

If 3x + logx = 30, then what is x?

Solution with W-Function...
The equation is 3x+Logx=30(1) we know that accept w*e^w=y=>w=W(k,y)..k in Z.But if w=3x=>3x*e^(3x)=y=>3x=W(k,y)(2) but from (1)… Log(3x)+3x=Logy=>Log3+Logx+3x=Logy=> Logx+3x=Logy-Log3=Log(y/3). Because we have the same equation {1,2} and then Log(y/3)=30=>y=3*e^30.Then General Solution is

3x=W(k,y)=>x=1/3W(k,3*e^30),, k in Z.

Comment: Program in mathematica .....................                                                     
Reduce[3*x + Log[x] == 30, x],,                                                                                 
C[1] \[Element] Integers &&  x == 1/3 ProductLog[C[1], 3 E^30]

Comment: What is the question you want answered by this community?

Comment: in() ..Solve[3*x + Log[x] == 30, x, Reals] ..out() {{x -> 1/3 ProductLog[3 E^30]}}..This mean C(1)=0 from before..

Comment: to find someone graphical method ...

Comment: Does `Plot[{Log[x], 30 - 3 x}, {x, 1, 12}]` count as a graphical method of solving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10472/marking-points-of-intersection-between-two-curves

Answer (score 1):

For a purely graphical approach, you can use the options `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` and post-process the `Plot` output to add text elements:

```
f[x_] = 3 x + Log[x] - 30;
Normal[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 20}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]] /. 
  p_Point :> {p, Text[Style[p[[1, 1]], 16], {-1, 5} + p[[1]]]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally transcendental equations are numerically solved with `NSolve` or `FindRoot`.

```
f[x_] = 3 x + Log[x] - 30;

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

```
NSolve[f[x] == 0 && x > 5 && x < 15]
(* {{x -> 9.25816}} *)

FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, 10}]
(* {x -> 9.25816} *)
```

Comment: ok many thanks is correct