# NArgMax solutions' intersection plotted but not solved for

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Defining two functions via `NArgMax` and plotting, there is an intersection and the `Plot` function works. But trying to solve for the intersection with various methods from Mathematica Stackexchange generates various errors. How to solve an equation system in which the functions are defined by the outputs of `NArgMax`?

MWE

```
    Clear[pl, ph, pil, pih, plbr, phbr]
pil[pl_, ph_] := pl*(ph - 2*pl);
pih[pl_, ph_] := ph*(1 - ph + pl);
plbr[ph_] = plbr[ph_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pil[pl, ph], pl]
phbr[pl_] = phbr[pl_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pih[pl, ph], ph]
NSolve[{plbr[ph] == pl, phbr[pl] == ph}, {pl, ph}]
FindRoot[{plbr[ph] == pl, 
  phbr[pl] == ph}, {{pl, 0.5, 0, 1}, {ph, 0.9, 0, 2}}]
```

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph/156975#156975) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10472/marking-points-of-intersection-between-two-curves) show a workaround:

```
    plt3 = Show[plt1, plt2]
Point@
 Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections@plt3
```

which finds some intersections, fails to find some and adds some wrong ones.

My full code with various solution attempts:

```
    Clear[a, b, c, e, ql, qh, pl, ph, cl, ch, cdf, pil, pih, plbr]
$Assumptions = 
  0 <= a < b < c && 0 < e < 1 && 0 < ql < qh && 0 < pl < ph < c*qh && 
   pl < c*ql && 0 < cl < ch < ph && cl < pl;
cdf[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, x < a}, {e*(x - a)/(b - a), 
     a <= x < b}, {e + (1 - e)*(x - b)/(c - b), b <= x < c}, {1, 
     x >= c}}];
pil[pl_, ph_] := (pl - cl)*(cdf[(ph - pl)/(qh - ql)] - cdf[pl/ql]);
pih[pl_, ph_] := (ph - ch)*(1 - cdf[(ph - pl)/(qh - ql)]);
a = 0.001; b = 0.5; c = 1.0; e = 0.9; cl = 0.; ch = 0.5;
ql = 1; qh = 1.6; qh2 = 1.8;
plbr[ph_] = plbr[ph_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pil[pl, ph], pl]
phbr[pl_] = phbr[pl_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pih[pl, ph], ph]
(*NSolve[{plbr[ph]\[Equal]pl,phbr[pl]\[Equal]ph},{pl,ph}]
FindRoot[{plbr[ph]\[Equal]pl,phbr[pl]\[Equal]ph},{{pl,(cl+c*ql)/2,cl,\
c*ql},{ph,(ch+c*qh)/2,ch,c*qh}}](*"The function value {-0.5`+Null} is \
not a list of numbers with dimensions"...*)
FindRoot[{plbr[phbr[pl]]\
\[Equal]pl},{{pl,(cl+c*ql)/2,cl,c*ql},{ph,(ch+c*qh)/2,ch,c*qh}}]*)

plbr[ph_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pil[pl, ph], pl]
phbr[pl_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pih[pl, ph], ph]
Reap[odsoln = 
   NDSolve[Evaluate[{yl'[ph] == plbr'[ph], yh'[pl] == phbr'[pl],(*yl[
      ch]\[Equal]plbr[ch]-ch,yh[cl]\[Equal]phbr[cl]-cl,*)
      yl[c*qh] == plbr[c*qh] - c*qh, yh[c*ql] == phbr[c*ql] - c*ql, 
      WhenEvent[{yl[ph] == 0, yh[pl] == 0}, Sow[{pl, ph}]]}], {yl[ph],
      yh[pl]}, {{pl, cl, c*ql}, {ph, ch, 
      c*qh}}];](*[[2,1]]*)
With[{eql = plbr[ph] - pl, 
  eqh = phbr[pl] - ph}, 
 roots = Reap[
    NDSolve[{yl'[ph] == D[eql, ph], yh'[pl] == D[eqh, pl], 
       yl[0] == (eql /. ph -> 0), yh[0] == (eqh /. pl -> 0), 
       WhenEvent[eql == 0 && eqh == 0, Sow[{pl, ph}]]}, {}, {{pl, cl, 
        c*ql}, {ph, ch, c*qh}}];][[2, 1]]]
plbr[ph_] := NArgMax[pil[pl, ph], pl]
phbr[pl_] := NArgMax[pih[pl, ph], ph]
(*plbr[ph_?NumericQ]:=NArgMax[pil[pl,ph],pl]
plbr2[ph_?NumericQ]:=NArgMax[pil2[pl,ph],pl]*)
yl = 
 ImplicitRegion[{plbr[ph] == pl}, {pl, ph}]
yh = ImplicitRegion[{plbr[ph] == pl}, {pl, ph}];
Solve[{{pl, ph} \[Element] f1, {pl, ph} \[Element] f2}, {pl, ph}]
```

Also tried

```
 plbr[ph_] := 
 FunctionInterpolation[
  ArgMax[{pil[pl, ph], cl <= pl <= c*ql}, pl], {ph, ch, c*qh}]
phbr[pl_] := 
 FunctionInterpolation[
  ArgMax[{pih[pl, ph], ch <= ph <= c*qh}, ph], {pl, cl, c*ql}]
NSolve[{plbr[ph] == pl, phbr[pl] == ph}, {pl, 
  ph}](*With plbr[ph_?NumericQ] gives pl\[Rule]1.` Null,ph\[Rule]1.` \
Null*)
```

The plotting code that works:

```
    Clear[a, b, c, e, ql, qh, qh2, pl, ph, cl, ch, cdf, pil, pil2, pih, \
plbr, plbr2, plt1, plt2]
$Assumptions = 
  0 <= a < b < c && 0 < e < 1 && 0 < ql < qh < qh2 && 
   0 < pl < ph < c*qh && pl < c*ql && 0 < cl < ch < ph && cl < pl;
pil[pl_, ph_] := (pl - cl)*(cdf[(ph - pl)/(qh - ql)] - cdf[pl/ql]);
pil2[pl_, ph_] := (pl - cl)*(cdf[(ph - pl)/(qh2 - ql)] - cdf[pl/ql]);
pih[pl_, ph_] := (ph - ch)*(1 - cdf[(ph - pl)/(qh - ql)]);
pih2[pl_, ph_] := (ph - ch)*(1 - cdf[(ph - pl)/(qh2 - ql)]);
cdf[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, x < a}, {e*(x - a)/(b - a), 
     a <= x < b}, {e + (1 - e)*(x - b)/(c - b), b <= x < c}, {1, 
     x >= c}}];
a = 0.001; b = 0.5; c = 1.0; e = 0.9; cl = 0; ch = 0.5;
ql = 1; qh = 1.6; qh2 = 1.8;
plbr[ph_] = plbr[ph_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pil[pl, ph], pl]
plbr2[ph_] = plbr2[ph_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pil2[pl, ph], pl]
phbr[pl_] = phbr[pl_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pih[pl, ph], ph]
phbr2[pl_] = phbr2[pl_?NumericQ] := NArgMax[pih2[pl, ph], ph]

plt1 = ParametricPlot[{{plbr[ph], ph}, {plbr2[ph], ph}}, {ph, ch, 
    c*qh2}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Blue}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Subscript[P, L], Subscript[P, H]}];
plt2 = ParametricPlot[{{pl, phbr[pl]}, {pl, phbr2[pl]}}, {pl, cl, 
    c*ql}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}];
Show[plt1, plt2]
```