What are the better ways to identify all the intersection points of two function graphs and label their coordinate values?
To identify all the intersection points between the two function graphsy=sinxand y=2sin(3x-Pi/6) within the domain 0<=x<=2Pi, my method is to solve the equation Sin[x] == 2 Sin[3 x - \[Pi]/6] for all roots in this domain, and then use the Table function to label all intersection points and their coordinate values on the graph.
This method is feasible, but are there any better methods? Code that is more concise and efficient?
My code is as follows:
expr = {Sin[x], 2 Sin[3 x - \[Pi]/6]}
intersectionConditions = 
 Solve[{Sin[x] == 2 Sin[3 x - \[Pi]/6], 0 <= x <= 2 \[Pi]}, x, 
   Reals] // FullSimplify
intersectionValues = 
  If[intersectionConditions != {}, 
   Table[{x, Sin[x]} /. intersectionConditions[[i]] // 
     FullSimplify, {i, 1, Length[intersectionConditions]}], 
   "intersection Does Not Exist"];
If[intersectionConditions != {}, {Table[{x, Sin[x]} /. 
      intersectionConditions[[i]] // FullSimplify // N, {i, 1, 
    Length[intersectionConditions]}]}]
Plot[expr, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5 \[Pi]}, Automatic}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 600, Epilog -> {
   If[intersectionConditions != {}, {PointSize[Medium], Red, 
     Point[intersectionValues], Style[FontSize -> Tiny], 
     Table[Text[intersectionValues[[p]] // N, 
       Offset[{-10, -18}, intersectionValues[[p]]]], {p, 1, 
       Length[intersectionValues], 1}]}]}]

The effect achieved is as follows:


Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10472/1871

One simple way would be to use the resource functions CurveIntersection and  IntersectionPlot by  Wolfram|Alpha Math Team
fun = {Sin[x], 2 Sin[3 x - Pi/6]}


cin = ResourceFunction["CurveIntersection"];

p = cin[fun, x, Reals, "Constraints" -> 0 <= x <= 2 Pi] // N // Values


{{0.20921, 0.207687}, {1.07035, 0.87737}, {2.38563, 0.68599},
{3.3508, -0.207687}, {4.21194, -0.87737}, {5.52722, -0.68599}}

pin = ResourceFunction["IntersectionPlot"];

plot = pin[fun, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]


Mouse pointing at the intersection points we can see their coordinates. Alternatively we could do:
text = Table[Text[Round[p[[i]], 0.01], p[[i]] + {0.25, 0.25}], {i, Length[p]}]

Show[plot, Graphics @ text]




Clear["`*"]
expr = {Sin[x], 2  Sin[3  x - \[Pi]/6]};
sol = SolveValues[{Sin[x] == 2  Sin[3  x - \[Pi]/6], 
      0 <= x <= 2  \[Pi]}, x] // N // Sort;
Plot[expr, {x, -1, 2  \[Pi]}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.017], Point[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ sol], Black,
    Table[Text[
     Round[{#, Sin[#]} &@sol[[i]], 
      0.01], {#, Sin[#]} &@sol[[i]] + {0.1, 0.1}], {i, 
     Length[sol]}]}]



I wrote one based on the content provided by the URL given by xzczd.

Clear["`*"]
expr = {Sin[x], 2  Sin[3  x - \[Pi]/6]};
points = 
 SolveValues[{Sin[x] == 2  Sin[3  x - \[Pi]/6], 0 <= x <= 2  \[Pi]}, 
    x] // N // Sort
plot = Plot[expr, {x, -1, 2  \[Pi]}, Mesh -> {points}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}, 
   Exclusions -> Range[-5  \[Pi]/2, 5  \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]]];
labels = 
  Table[Text[Round[{points[[i]], Sin[points[[i]]]}, 0.01], 
    Offset[{10, 10}, {points[[i]], Sin[points[[i]]]}], {1, 0}], {i, 
    Length[points]}];
Show[plot, Epilog -> labels]



Plot[{Sin[x], 2  Sin[3  x - \[Pi]/6]}, {x, 0, 2  Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {(Sin[#] - 2  Sin[3  # - \[Pi]/6]) &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]]]



Clear["`*"]
expr = {Sin[x], 2  Sin[3  x - \[Pi]/6]};
sol = SolveValues[{Sin[x] == 2  Sin[3  x - \[Pi]/6], 
     0 <= x <= 2  \[Pi]}, x] // N // Sort
plot = Plot[expr, {x, -1, 2  \[Pi]}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.017], Point[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ sol]}]


